# CCMenuItemSprite Not Responding To Touch in iOS8

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

My Cocos2D app utilizes a number of CCMenuItemSprite's for buttons (e.g. back button). When the button is on the left half of a landscape scene, it fails to respond to the touch. The buttons on the right half of the screen work fine. The code to initialize the button is straight forward:

```
CCSprite *normalSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MenuArrowButtonOblongNormal_iPad.png"];
CCSprite *selectedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MenuArrowButtonOblongSelected_iPad.png"];
CCMenuItemSprite *backButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:normalSprite
                                                       selectedSprite:selectedSprite
                                                               target:self
                                                             selector:@selector(returnToOptionsMenu)];

if (screenSizeInPixels.width == 1136.0f) {
        [backButton setScaleX:0.9375f];
        [backButton setScaleY:0.8322f];
        buttonHeight = 0.9f;
}

CCMenu *sceneSelectMenu;
sceneSelectMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: backButton,nil];
[sceneSelectMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:screenSize.height * 0.059f];
[sceneSelectMenu setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width*0.15, 
                                 screenSize.height * buttonHeight)];


[self addChild:sceneSelectMenu];

// And finally the back button label
CCLabelTTF *backButtonLabel;
backButtonLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", @"Enables user to exit the current screen and view the previous screen")
                                     fontName:@"Marker Felt"
                                     fontSize:scaledFontSize*1.3];
backButtonLabel.color = ccc3(255,255,255);
[backButtonLabel setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.5,0.5)];

backButtonLabel.position = ccp(screenSize.width * (0.14+labelOffset),
                               screenSize.height * labelHeight);
[self addChild:backButtonLabel z:2];
```

This is an older app that utilized Cocos2D version 1.1-RC0. I have made several updates to this code based on the suggested changes in [iPhone 6 and 6+ update patch for cocos2d 2.1](http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/iphone-6-and-6-update-patch-for-cocos2d-2-1/15213/4). But these primarily address resolution/scale factor issues.

If no one has seen this issue, can you suggest where in the cocos2D I might investigate to determine why the touches are not being detected/acted upon?

Comment: Post the entire code, including what you do to the items once created and how you create the menu and what you perhaps do to that. For instance changing position or anchorPoint of the item, or anchorpoint of the menu node will affect touch handling.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Per your request, I have included the entire code in the question. I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: try without changing the anchorpoint of items or nodes representing the item (ie backButtonLabel). Avoid scaling menu items too. You should probably consider wrapping each item in its own CCMenu node so that you have full control over the position of each item, because the CCMenu takes control over handling menu item positions and touch detection. So its best to apply any modifications only to the CCMenu node rather than the items it contains.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I removed the label completely and the scaling code. I also removed alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding. These changes had no impact. If I set the menu position at 0.34*screenSize.width, it works. But if I set it at 0.33*screenSize.width, it stops working. That is for an iPhone5s. Would it help to set any breakpoints within the cocos2d code to see what is happening? If so, please suggest a section of code.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Another interesting anomaly is that when I position the menu button at 0.34*screenSize.width or greater, then any touch to the left of the menu button all the way to the left edge (as well as a touch to the menu button) will be detected and acted upon. Finally, this was not a problem in iOS7. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I've logged touch points in ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch. Within this method is a line of code: CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];  When I touch the screen in a straight horizontal line at the bottom of the screen and move from right to left, touchLocation.x never changes, but touchLocation.y increases until the midpoint of the screen. After that, touchLocation.y NEVER increases. Consequently, openGL and box2d coordinates also stop changing. Is there some new conversion required for iOS8 or a different framework required? Or am I misinterpreting this?